# Trouble with Drawing Lines from Higher Timeframes

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Hi StackOverflow community,

I'm encountering an issue with an indicator I've been working on, specifically regarding the correct drawing of lines with data from higher timeframes onto lower timeframes. Here's a breakdown of the problem:

I've developed an indicator that draws lines using data from higher timeframes. However, when I test the indicator by drawing lines from a weekly timeframe onto a daily timeframe, the lines do not appear as expected.

```
 // Add an input to select the higher timeframe higherTF =
 input.timeframe("", title="Higher Timeframe", inline="1",
 confirm=true)
 
 haTicker = ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid)
 
 // Use request.security to get data from the higher timeframe/ haOpen
 = request.security(haTicker, higherTF, open, barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) haHigh = request.security(haTicker,
 higherTF, high,  barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
 haLow = request.security(haTicker, higherTF, low,  barmerge.gaps_off,
 lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) haClose = request.security(haTicker,
 higherTF, close,  barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
 
 ///Arrays for the lines var uptrendlines = array.new_line()  var
 downtrendlines = array.new_line()
 
 drawdowntrendline(x1, y1, x2, y2) =>
     array.push(downtrendlines,line.new(x1, y1, x2, y2 - (x2 - x1), extend=extend.right, color=color.blue))
 
 drawuptrendline(x1, y1, x2, y2) =>
     array.push(uptrendlines,line.new(x1, y1, x2, y2 + (x2 - x1), extend=extend.right, color=color.blue))
 
 isGreen = haClose >= haOpen isRed = haClose < haOpen
 
 // Check if transition from green to red // Check for green close on
 uptrend haBull = isRed[1] and isGreen
 
 // Check for red close on downtrend haBear = isGreen[1] and isRed
 
 //Calculation of downtrend line if (haBear) and barstate.isconfirmed
     // Set origin time to pivot bar
     originTime = bar_index[1]
 
     // Set origin price
     originPrice = haOpen
 
     // Set end time 
     endTime = originTime + 1
 
     // Set end price
     endPrice = haLow
 
     // Draw Gann fan
     drawdowntrendline(originTime, haHigh[1], originTime + 3, haHigh[1])
 
 
 //Calculation of uptrend line if (haBull) and barstate.isconfirmed
     // Set origin time to pivot bar
     originTime = bar_index[1]
 
     // Set origin price
     originPrice = haOpen
 
     // Set end time 
     endTime = originTime + 1
 
     // Set end price
     endPrice = haHigh
 
     // Draw Line
     drawuptrendline(originTime, haLow[1], originTime + 3, haLow[1])
```

[picture of weekly timeframe with weekly data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYlOl.jpg)

[picture ofdaily timeframe with weekly data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Tw9.jpg)

To troubleshoot, I've taken the following steps:

- Traced the lines from the weekly timeframe using data from the weekly timeframe itself.
- Checked if the drawn lines display correctly on a different timeframe, specifically the daily timeframe, while still using data from the weekly timeframe.

Unfortunately, the lines do not match up as expected. It seems that the discrepancy arises when using the weekly data on the daily timeframe.

I've reviewed my code and compared it against similar implementations, but I haven't been able to pinpoint the issue. It's essential for my indicator's functionality that these lines are accurately drawn across different timeframes.

I'd greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to address this problem. If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has expertise in dealing with drawing lines across different timeframes in indicators, your input would be invaluable.

Thank you in advance for your help and guidance!